# expected a type specifier in C

Tags: c

All of my programs before have been working well with C except for today. For some reason I keep getting "expected a type specifier"

I am confused why this is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
printf("Hello World"); // error: expected a type specifer

int test = 90;
printf("%d", test); // same error here: expected a type specifier 
// also getting "variable "test" is not a type name"
```

Comment: Is this an extracted snippet or the whole file?

Comment: this is the whole file. I am not using any other C file

Comment: I don't believe you're allowed to have top-level statements in C

Comment: The code needs to be in a `main()` function.

Comment: wow i am so dumb. i never included the main function. thank you. im still brand new to C

Comment: @Vigilante Change the compiler!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have statements outside of a function in C.  That's what is causing the errors you're seeing.

The `main` function serves at the starting point for a C program, so start by putting the statements in that function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

    int test = 90;
    printf("%d", test);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah i dont know how i forgot about the main function. thank you